# How to write a CSV string on disk in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, csv

I have a foreach loop in which I am creating a CSV string from a datatable. I am using File.WriteAllText method to write the files onto the disk.
It is creating a new .csv file on the specified path after each iteration of the loop but each new file contains data of its previous files too. Below is my sample code:

```
 foreach (string CIInfo in CiInformation)
        {
            string[] CIId = CIInfo.Split(',');
            string query1 = "Some Query"
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, conn);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 50000;
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
            string CSV = DataTableToCSV(dt, ',');
            File.WriteAllText("D:\\NonMsCSV\\" + CIId[0] + ".csv", CSV);
```

Is there a way to create a new file after each iteration which contains only its own data and not of its predecessors? 
Any help would be really appreciated.

```
 public static string DataTableToCSV(DataTable datatable, char seperator)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(datatable.Columns[i]);
            if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
                sb.Append(seperator);
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
        foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(dr[i].ToString());

                if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
                    sb.Append(seperator);
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Your code is not formatted and enough. Please provide full and proper code.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: The read/write csv is the most common duplicate of the csv tag.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with `DataTableToCSV(dt, ',');`. Can you show us this method?

Comment: And from the documentation [DataTable.Load Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx): _If the DataTable already contains rows, the incoming data from the data source is merged with the existing rows._ So you are passing the whole data to the DataTableToCSV.

Comment: Ha ha, modern CSV format uses \t for columns and \r\n for rows :) Think about it.

Comment: added the DataTableToCSV method

Comment: @alerya, wait what? Do you have the specification of this Modern way? Because the rfc 4180 is clear. there is no gain for `\t`. You won't have a table display in your text file if column data doesnt have the same side. Common c# CSV lib use comma as default separator. And the Copy past argument in excel is broken has `" "` field delimitor won't be trimed; Csv is clear and well define. For the future may the IT use Csv Library and stop this none sense. I don't get why someone would like to change a separator, Did someone ever change Json `[{}]` to `~`?

Answer (score -2):

Every iteration, you are *adding* to the same data table. Use one data table instance per loop and you will have only that data in your file:

```
foreach (string CIInfo in CiInformation)
{
    var localTable = new DataTable();

    string[] CIId = CIInfo.Split(',');
    string query1 = "Some Query"
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 50000;
        localTable .Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }

    string CSV = DataTableToCSV(localTable, ',');
    File.WriteAllText("D:\\NonMsCSV\\" + CIId[0] + ".csv", CSV);
}
```